# Warning: while trying to convert java byte[] to C unsigned char*

Tags: java, c, arrays, java-native-interface

I am writing a JNI. In that, my Java program takes an Image byte array using ByteOutputStream() and then this array is used to call a function in C that converts byte array to unsigned char*. Here is the code:

```
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_ImageConversion_covertBytes(JNIEnv *env, jobject obj, jbyteArray array) 
 {
    unsigned char* flag = (*env)->GetByteArrayElements(env, array, NULL);
    jsize size = (*env)->GetArrayLength(env, array);

    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    printf("%c", flag[i]);}
 }
```

In this I keep getting a warning when I compile:

> warning: initializing 'unsigned char *' with an expression of type 'jbyte *' (aka 'signed char *') converts between pointers to integer types with different sign [-Wpointer-sign]
>
> unsigned char* flag = (*env)->GetByteArrayElements(env, array, NULL);

How can I remove this warning? I want to print the all characters.

Comment: try `unsigned char* flag` => `signed char* flag` or cast pointers explicitly (if you want to print, then just use signed char)

Comment: As @Jean-FrançoisFabre wrote, use `signed char *`. Actually, that is what the warning is telling you too. Error messages and warnings are not just gibberish, they usually do have a meaning. This one tells you that you are initializing an `unsigned char *` with a `signed char *`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The warning exists because the sign change might be important. In JNI the `jbyte` corresponds to Java `byte` which is a signed 8-bit integer; in C it is explicitly `signed char`.

However, it is OK to access any object with any character pointer, so you can cast to `unsigned char` explicitly:

```
unsigned char* flag = (unsigned char*)(*env)->GetByteArrayElements(env, array, NULL);
```

Alternatively, you can declare `flag` as `signed char`:

```
signed char* flag = (*env)->GetByteArrayElements(env, array, NULL);
```

This is fine for `printf("%c\n", flag[i]);` because `%c` requires that the argument be an integer; the integer is then converted to `unsigned char` so both `signed` and `unsigned char` will do.

However 3rd option would be to use neither - if you just want to write them to the terminal, use a `void *` pointer and `fwrite`:

```
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL 
Java_ImageConversion_covertBytes(JNIEnv *env, jobject obj, jbyteArray array) 
{
    void *flag = (*env)->GetByteArrayElements(env, array, NULL);
    jsize size = (*env)->GetArrayLength(env, array);
    fwrite(flag, 1, size, stdout);     
}
```

and let `fwrite` worry about the looping.